# Windows 10 SDK won't install to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp

I've been trying to get Visual Studio and the Windows 10 SDK to work for over a week now. First I couldn't install Visual Studio. That problem was resolved by uninstalling EVERYTHING vaguely related to VS2015, thanks to manually going through everything, but also the Visual Studio "TotalUninstaller".

Plot twist: Now that I've managed to get VS2015 installed and running, I can't get the SDK to install. I've selected it with the installation process, tried to modify VS after, tried to install it with the Standalone installer, but none of it works. Every time, the installer doesn't notice anything wrong, all the tools appear in the start menu, a new "Program Files (x86)/WindowsKits/10.0" folder appears, with all the correct files, but VS can't open any UWP projects, can't create new any, and the SDK doesn't appear in the Extensions list.

When I uninstalled everything, there was only one thing I couldn't get rid of: "Windows 10 for Mobile Image - 10.0.10240.0". It just opens, runs for a second, and closes, achieving nothing in the process. As I couldn't get rid of this, I manually deleted any "Windows Kits" related folder in Program Files, Program Files (x86), ProgramData, and anything in the AppData folder. But this piece of fluffy garbage didn't leave my installed programs list. Could this have something to do with not being able to install the Windows 10 SDK correctly?

I looked in the install logs, and this is the only error I saw:

```
[371C:398C][2016-08-08T21:13:35]i301: Applying execute package: {7a68448b-9cf2-4049-bd73-5875f1aa7ba2}, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7a68448b-9cf2-4049-bd73-5875f1aa7ba2}\vsupdate_KB3022398.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7a68448b-9cf2-4049-bd73-5875f1aa7ba2}\vsupdate_KB3022398.exe" -quiet -burn.related.patch -burn.ignoredependencies={248fcd1e-5ee1-421d-893f-ec0a94dd7b01} -burn.ancestors={248fcd1e-5ee1-421d-893f-ec0a94dd7b01}'
[371C:398C][2016-08-08T21:13:35]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to create embedded process atpath: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7a68448b-9cf2-4049-bd73-5875f1aa7ba2}\vsupdate_KB3022398.exe
[371C:398C][2016-08-08T21:13:35]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to run embedded bundle.
[371C:398C][2016-08-08T21:13:35]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to run bundle as embedded from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7a68448b-9cf2-4049-bd73-5875f1aa7ba2}\vsupdate_KB3022398.exe
[371C:398C][2016-08-08T21:13:35]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to execute EXE package.
[287C:137C][2016-08-08T21:13:35]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
```

It appears in every log when I try to install vs2015 with the right option ticked, or when I use the standalone installer. I've looked in `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` and there is no `{7a68448b-9cf2-4049-bd73-5875f1aa7ba2}` folder, and none of the other folders contain "vsupdate_KB3022398.exe". It looks like this is the root of the problem.

EDIT: I've created the folder that was missing and added "vsupdate_KB3022398.exe" to it (found it online, hosted on a Microsoft server), and there are no more errors left. However, the problem still isn't fixed. The SDK simply refuses to show up. I think I'm going to have to do a clean install.

Comment: install the SDK via this installer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: Already tried that :/ (in the post I said I tried using the standalone installer)

Comment: post the log files

Comment: Which ones? There are hundreds in %Temp%.

Comment: look which has SDK in the name

Comment: I've added the error from the log to my OP.

Answer (score 3):

I had the issue of Windows 10 SDK 14393 failing to install on Windows 7 OS. This problem occurred when installing as part of Visual Studio 2015 and also running the Standalone Installer for the Windows 10 SDK 14393. According to the logs, the Windows Desktop Extension SDK failed to install.

As a work-around I installed Windows 10 SDK 10586 (Installed successfully)
Then I installed Windows 10 SDK 14393 (Installed successfully)
Both versions of the Windows 10 SDK appear as choices under Target Platform Version in Visual Studio 2015 for me.

Apparently the Windows 10 SDK 14393 installer is missing something which it requires to run successfully on Windows 7. (Something that must be present in the previous version)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the difficulty.  There are 2 known issues that are causing 'Fatal Error' in the Windows SDK install.
[See the Windows SDK Tools Issues Forum.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1fd20d8-b1ce-4805-96e5-c7876b441d56/known-issue-windows-10-sdk-14393-fails-to-install-with-a-fatal-error-0x80070643-failed-to?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues)

You probably have (had) a pre-release of the SDK and one of the contracts installed is causing MDMerge to fail during setup.  Uninstalling the prerelease version of the SDK should avoid this issue.

Thanks,
kevin

Comment: I'd already tried uninstalling it (as I said in my OP), and nothing worked. I finished by being forced to do a clean install of Windows.

Comment: Read ur link. I have nothing regarding *ANY* Software Dev Kit in my Add/Remove. Pitiful ARP management per usual. Why I am not shocked? So I take it the 'new' SDK installer and/or VS 'installer' simply cannot check for an old version and replace or patch to new version? God forbid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the MDMerge problem, after uninstalling all previous Windows 10 SDK toolkits, still couldn't install. Fixed it by moving the contents of: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10", ran the installer again and it installed fine.

Comment: What do you mean by 'ran the installer'? The downloaded Windows installer or the install executed during dependency check. MDMerge issue happened to me when I tried to start a new C++ project for first time under Win7 running VS Community 2015. VS started the SDK install.. I have also seen searches say that Windows 10 SDK installer will not work under Windows 7. Do you have Win7?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3054875/windows-sdk-10-0-14393-0-install-fails-on-windows-7 is related to mdmerge issue. This is error I get. He used a win8/10 dll apparently to 'fix'.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it kind of worked for me. Remove everything in the linker ( PROJECT -> LINKER -> Input -> Additional Dependencies, as can be seen in this screenshot

[image]